# Android Studio Instant Run restart application always

Tags: android-studio, android-instant-run

In  Android Studio, the "Instant Run" function  "Apply changes" [image] restart application always, even if no change in code (Android Studio 2.3.0 - MacOS 10.12.3). This happen when application is in Debug and paused on a break point, if then I try to apply change the app restart [image]

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }



    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        //instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instant Run is always disabled in the debugger:

> On Android Studio 2.3, if you deploy your app by clicking Debug , pushing subsequent code changes by clicking Apply Changes  always results in a cold swap. To learn more, go to [issue #234401](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=234401).

From https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run

Other than that, your configuration seems to check all the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms) Apply Changes actions are only available when you meet the following conditions:

- You build the APK of your app using a debug build variant.
- You deploy your app to a target device or emulator that runs Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher.

Answer (score -1):

As per the android [docs:](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run)

**Disable automatic activity restart**

When performing a hot swap, your app keeps running but Android Studio automatically restarts the current activity. To disable this default setting:

Open the Settings or Preferences dialog:

- On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the menu bar.
- On Mac OSX, select Android Studio > Preferences from the menu bar.
- Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
- Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes.

If automatic activity restart is disabled, you can manually restart
   the current activity from the menu bar by selecting Run > Restart
   Activity.